# How do I execute the CTRL + H function in a Microsoft Access query automatically?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have numbers displayed as Ranges Ex. 3-7 Days or 24-72 Hours.  I need to change these to just a number like 168 or 72 so I can ultimately do comparisons or if statements.  I know i can just click CTRL H and go through each condition to format the data, but I have been trying to find a way to have this happen through the query.  I am very new to Access so I may be thinking about this all wrong.  I tried typing this `Expr1: Replace("0-4 Hours", "0-4 Hours", "4")` in the field and sometimes it asks for a parameter but it just creates a column called Expr1 with the parameter in it.  I followed the syntax i found on this site for replace function so i must be way off.

Comment: Query is looking for a field named `0-4 Hours` which of course it can't find, hence the prompt. Correct syntax: `Expr1: Replace([fieldname], "0-4 Hours", "4")`. However, this calc result will only show for records that have `0-4 Hours` value. Dynamically calculating this for every record will require different approach.

Comment: Are Days and Hours the only units used?

Answer (score 0):

Query is looking for a field named `0-4 Hours` which of course it can't find, hence the prompt (which should always happen, not just sometimes so that is a mystery). Correct syntax:
`Expr1: Replace([fieldname], "0-4 Hours", "4")`.
However, this calc result will show only for records that have `0-4 Hours` value. Dynamically calculating this for every record should be possible with:

`SELECT *, Val(Mid([fieldname], InStr([fieldname], "-")+1)) As Num FROM tablename;`

Every record must have value because Null will cause error.

If the unit (Days, Hours, etc) is not same for all records, this gets even more complicated. If Days and Hours are the only units involved and you want to convert all to Hours:

`Val(Mid([fieldname], InStr([fieldname], "-")+1)) * IIf(InStr([fieldname],"Days")>0,24,1) As Num`

Any more complication and a VBA custom function would likely be required.